# Import Image as Plane imports only part of the image

Tags: image, import

I'm very new to blender, am trying to convert a grayscale image (that I drew) to 3D so that I can see what I have, and re-sculpt by adjusting the drawing in Photoshop. When I Import Image as Plane, only about a third of the image gets imported, usually the central portion. I can get around this by doubling the image's canvas size, but is there something I am doing wrong that makes this image come in cropped, instead of completely?

Comment: You probably need to UV unwrap the plane , Press U in edit mode > unwrap. now try

Comment: @Knuckles209cp That's wrong, the addon unwraps it.

Comment: @paul-ny What's the images resolution?

Comment: The full image is a square about 5,000 x 5,000 pixels (res @600 ppi). The image imported completely after I made it about 15,000 px on a side. But then I tried importing a jpg that was a detail of the full image, about 2,000 px on a side, and once again what imported into Blender was only about the center third of it .

Comment: If you are using the image just as reference add an empty as image or use the image as background.

Comment: I'm not using the image as reference, I'm using it to create a 3-D relief based on its grayscale value, with the Displace modifier, and I'm wanting to know why the Import function only imported the central third of the image.

Comment: This would be a bug, most likely caused by the large file size. The addon is supposed to unwrap the mesh and apply a material, and the mesh is supposed to reflect the size/aspect ratio of the image file. However changing render engines after importing might possibly mess it up. How does the texture render?

Comment: I don't know at least half of the terminology here, but if "how does the texture render" means how does Blender do at creating the 3-D relief from the grayscale image, it seems to do it very well. When the imported image was 1/3 the size of the original one, this bug was still present. I might try a truly small image to see if it's different. What would "changing render engines after importing" be? I haven't clicked "render" at all, have just looked at 3d scene (after subdividing the plane a _lot_, like 10 times.

Comment: Depending how you subdivide that could theoretically do it, and it doesn't sound like you changed render engines. I wanted to see if the texture was just displaying in the viewport incorrectly, but when you hit render the issue is still there, so it must be something else. Try a smaller file, if that works I think your issue is a bug.

Comment: what version of blender are you using? How much ram have you got on your machine? what format is the image in question? can you share it?

Comment: I just did a test: 5k x 5k pixel 16 bit image, "import images" as planes with no issues...

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.73 on a Mac (OS 10.6.8), 8 GB of RAM; image is JPG. I'll try to go in and make a screen shot to share. (I don't yet know enough to render through the camera).

Comment: If this works, here's a screen shot of Blender after I  imported the image appearing below it. <img src=http://www.paulozelinsky.com/temp/screen_shot_cropped_blender_import.jpg" >

Comment: It didn't work, and I ran out of time to edit. Here: http://www.paulozelinsky.com/temp/screen_shot_cropped_blender_import.jpg

Comment: This may add to the confusion or it may clarify it: when I set the method to display 3D view to "rendered", I get a strange image that I see is applying my entire image as texture to the 3d-from-grayscale (partial) image. http://www.paulozelinsky.com/temp/screen_shot_texture_3d_mismatch.png

Comment: Try properties/ image mapping / extend /

Comment: Thank you, node, but I haven't been able to figure out what or where properties/image mapping/extend is (BTW I'm using Blender 2.73 on a Mac). How,ever a tutorial I watched led me to try choosing UV in Texture Coordinates in the Displace modifier panel, and that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: You're last comment @paul-ny allowed me to fix this same problem. Setting the Texture coordinates to UV instead of Normal fixed the exact issue.